# WARNING: JSF1074: Managed bean named 'bean' has already been registered

Tags: jsf, annotations, managed-bean

I'm using mojarra JSF 2.2.

The beans that we have defined are anotation based eg.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "codeBean")
@ViewScoped
public class CodeRuleBean implements Serializable
```

I am using tomcat 7.0.53 to deploy the same. However, I am getting a warning that says

> WARNING: JSF1074: Managed bean named 'codeBean' has already been registered. Replacing existing managed bean class type `com.myclass.rule.ui.CodeRuleBean` with `com.myclass.rule.ui.CodeRuleBean`.

There is none in `faces-config.xml`. I am using `faces-config.xml` only to define the navigation rules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee \
              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">


    <application>
        <navigation-handler>com.configurator.application.navigator.MyNavigator</navigation-handler>
    </application>

    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>codeRulePage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/rule/shortCodeMain.xhtml
            </to-view-id>
            <redirect />
            <to-flow-document-id />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/rule/shortCodeMain.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>successPage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/rule/successCodeRule.xhtml
            </to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</<faces-config>
```

Here is the `web.xml`, it does not contain any web listeners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>MyWeb</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cachePreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: post your faces-config and web.xml

Comment: here is my Faces-Config

Comment: Dont see it, please paste both faces-config and web.xml

Comment: just edited the question.. please check if it is visible

Comment: I'm getting the same warning for all beans, no idea why.

Comment: This could be caused by a dirty build which bundled duplicate classes or JSF implementation JARs. Where exactly the fault is cannot be answered without knowing detail about the build procedure.

Answer (score 13):

I think you have registered multiple listener for jsf space. Check it out. If you have `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` in your web.xml remove it.

Because `com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer` registers `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` on `onStartup` method.